# How can I make a tag as a web link box.net

Tags: box-api

I saw this in the salesforce box.net app that by pressing the tag on box.net redirects the user to the salesforce record. But if I add a link to a tag this doesnt work. Does anyone knows how I can make it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce tags are a special type of tag, that's not yet available for other developers to use.  You can tag files through our tagging APIs, but the reference tags for Salesforce aren't scalable just yet.